# Can't delete multiple rows from a table where operation is true in another table

Tags: mysql

How I can select and delete all those rows?

phpMyAdmin gives me:

```
#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

DELETE FROM zoo_category_item WHERE (SELECT id FROM zoo_item WHERE params = '1')
```

Comment: `DELETE FROM zoo_category_item WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM zoo_item WHERE params = '1')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need some connection between the tables.  Something like:

```
DELETE FROM zoo_category_item
    WHERE zoo_category_item.id in (SELECT id FROM zoo_item WHERE params = '1');
```

I don't know the name of the appropriate column, though.

You are getting the error because the subquery returns more than one value.  In the context of the `where`, MySQL would expect a scalar subquery -- one row, one column.

If you want to delete all rows in `zoo_category_item` if that condition is true, then you would do:

```
DELETE FROM zoo_category_item
    WHERE exists (SELECT id FROM zoo_item WHERE params = '1');
```